# New & Improved PHP Session Redirect Problem

Tags: php, forms, session, post, redirect

I'm working on a multi-page form. Here's the outline of its function:

**Part One:** Collect Form Input Fields -> Sends user to transfer.php using POST method

**Part Two:** transfer.php | Validates that nothing is empty -> Stores $_POST variables into a $_SESSION -> Redirects user to next part of the form.

**Part Three:** Second Part of Form | Maintains the session from the first form -> Adds new variables to the session -> Preps for everything to get emailed

I've been reading how using header( location: ) etc drops session information. The solution people seem to find is to validate the form on page, then direct the user using the action field of the form.

---

**The problem I'm having:**
Where the form redirects is based on the input from the form. There are actually 8 potential forms that the user could be forwarded to depending on what they input during the first form.

> I've tried SID techniques and the
>   SESSION variables show up as
>   registered, but they all display
>   &NULL.

**Question:** How can I get the session variables to display on the next page?

---

Here's the code I have so far:

Part 1: the form

```
<form method="POST" action="transfer.php">
... all my form elements with proper names
</form>
```

Part 2: transfer.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = $_POST;

// project_type would store an url for the corresponding 2nd part of the form
$redirect = $_SESSION['project_type'];
$redirect .= "?phpSESSID=".session_id();
header("Location: $redirect");
exit();
?>
```

Part 3: the next form

```
<?php
// initialize a session
session_start();
echo "<p>Session ID: " . session_id() . "</p>";                     
echo "<p>Vardump Set Off Page: ";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</p>";
?>

<form method="...... the rest of the form etc
```

---

I know that the post is making it to transfer.php correctly.
I know that the content of $_POST is being copied to $_SESSION correctly.
I know that somewhere during the redirect, the session variables are being set to &NULL

Here's what the var_dump looks like after the user gets redirected to the 2nd part of the form.

```
array(18) { ["project_type"]=> &NULL ["project_timeframe"]=> &NULL ["company_name"]=> &NULL ["company_address"]=> &NULL ["company_city"]=> &NULL ["company_state"]=> &NULL ["company_zipcode"]=> &NULL ["company_phone"]=> &NULL ["company_website"]=> &NULL ["contact_name"]=> &NULL ["contact_title"]=> &NULL ["contact_email"]=> &NULL ["contact_phone"]=> &NULL ["contact_primary_phone_type"]=> &NULL ["contact_phone_alt"]=> &NULL ["contact_alternate_phone_type"]=> &NULL ["contact_preferences"]=> &NULL ["contact_preferences_additional"]=> &NULL }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `session_start();` at the top of the page.
There is no need for the `session_id($_GET['phpSESSID']);` unless you are changing to a different session.

EDIT:

Also in `transfer.php` you just want all the posts to be saved to the session so just do:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

ALSO: remove this line: `session_write_close();`

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice - removed the line! I'm still having issues with the variables all showing up as &NULL though.

Comment: did you make sure all the `$_POST`s were not `null`?

Comment: Yes sir. I tested a var_dump($_POST); on the transfer.php and it held everything. Then after moving the variables to session in transfer.php I tried a var_dump($_SESSION); and it displayed all the variables with their contents...

Comment: @Will, ok so what is the issue?

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION); on part three shows "array(18) { ["project_type"]=> &NULL ["project_timeframe"]=> &NULL ["company_name"]=> &NULL ["company_address"]=> &NULL ["company_city"]=> &NULL....." ----- its emptying every variable during the redirect.

Comment: I have no idea. All I know is that $_SESSION is storing the variables correctly during the transfer.php part - but when they get pulled up in the next part, every variable shows &NULL.

Comment: Removed the session_write_close(); line as instructed. Deleted the session and started from scratch - still not having any luck.

Comment: Updated the code in the original post to show the new revisions.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the fact I'm incorporating this session into a wordpress theme is the problem.